# Navigation Drawer closes with pause

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I use sample of navigation drawer from http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. But everytime when I call click events, navigation drawer closes with pause: change image, close 3-6dp,stopping to 2-3 seconds and then close fully. Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Don't you make some heavy work with high computation cost on close event?

Comment: I think no, because it is sample. And I do not find other such problem.

Comment: can you post the solution as an answer for other people who may face the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem. I call transaction Fragment method in onDrawerClosed(). And this work without any pause.

```
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    transaction(n);
                    //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

private void transaction(int position){
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
}
```

where, n is static int and equals of position listview item.